# How to fold Org-mode files in VS-Code based on chapters, which do not have a closing tag?

Tags: org-mode, code-folding

Using Visual Studio Code with the Explicit Folding extension, I am trying to configure it so that the text is folded according to chapters, subchapters, ... in Org-mode files.

The Org-mode syntax for the text would be:

```
* Level 1 chapter

Text 1

** Level 2 chapter

Text 2

*** Level 3 chapter

Text 3

...
```

So there are tags that indicate the beginning of a block (*, **, ***), but the end of it is implicit.

How can I write the `setting.json` configuration file so that I get the behaviour I need?

All I could do so far is:

```
{
    "editor.showFoldingControls": "always",
    "explicitFolding.rules": {
        "org": [
            {
                "begin": "* ",
                "end": "#*"
            },
        ]
    },
    "explicitFolding.autoFold": "all",
    "explicitFolding.debug": true
}
```

This works correctly, but it needs the closing "#*" tag in the text. Without it I get nothing.

Is there a way to achieve this with this approach? Is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason of the issue. The Explicit Folding extension is working fine, the problem is that I also had an old version of the Org Mode extension (by "vscode-org-mode"). Updating this from version 0.5 to version 1.0 solved my problem.

Now the text folds correctly without the need of a closing tag.